# Why do principal energy levels in an atom get closer together as n increases?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atoms

The title says it all. Reasons that I can supply include: increased nuclear charge increasingly catches up in terms of influence to the increasing shielding and proof by contradiction in that if the space remained the same there would be negligible nuclear pull on the valence electrons and so this must not be the case. What is a comprehensive explanation for why this phenomenon is so?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not at all clear what system you're talking about in the question? I guess the hydrogen atom? (The same thing would be true for particle-in-a-box, metals, etc.)

Comment: I'm talking about any atom.

Answer (score 1):

That's an artifact of Euclidean space and the geometry of the problem (as explained in another answer), and the fact that the energy of an electron is constrained. As you move an electron away from a nucleus, the Coulombic attraction decreases, and the total energy of an electron in a state further removed from the nucleus correspondingly also decreases. A bound electron infinitely far from the nucleus has zero potential energy and zero total energy (since it is bound).

That leaves the question of how to decrease the energy between zero and a finite value in an infinite number of steps. There are many ways of doing this (any potential function with the form $-kr^{-n}$ will do the trick), but ultimately you have to allow the separation between energy levels to go to zero, otherwise you can't have infinitely many energy levels.

That is not entirely satisfactory. It kicks the can down the road and requires an answer to "why are there infinitely many energy levels?" I'll let someone else answer that in detail, but it is related to the fact that for high energies (a near free electron, say) the behavior of the system approaches the classical limit. In a classical Coulombic potential the allowed levels form a continuum, a key difference between classical and quantum systems (although that is again a bit of a circular explanation).

Answer (score 0):

The energy levels for an atom are similar to a "particle in a box", except that the walls have a different shape. When you analyzed the "particle in a box" situation, you used a rectangular box. An atom is spherical, so the walls of the atom open outwards at the same rate as the sphere increases in surface area. You should have noticed that the energy levels for a "particle in a box" decreased in distance at higher energy levels. The surface area of the sphere brings the energy levels even closer.

Answer (score 0):

It is to do with the way the potential energy changes with distance, which is different in different cases so there is nothing 'special' about an atom. As quantum number increases (a) in a harmonic oscillator, energy levels are equally spaced, (b) in rigid rotor rotational motion they diverge, (c) in the anharmonic oscillator (e.g. Morse potential) they become closer and (d) in the particle in a box they diverge.